# Userscript to simulate click on react managed button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, userscripts

I want to write a userscript for Tampermonkey, i.e. in vanilla JavaScript. The userscript shall simulate a click on the "Paste Text" button on the website https://quillbot.com/summarize. This button is a React-managed `<div>`.

I tried using the `.click()` method of the `div`, but nothing happens.

Comment: well the event is on `'.MuiBox-root.css-1uxtb13'` but they have logic to stop it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Paste Text" button, of course, uses some way to interact with the clipboard. From its behavior, it seems that they use the [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API), with the corresponding user-granted permission.

Unfortunately, it's not possible to trigger interaction with the clipboard without a user interaction. Quote from [relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30810322/1083697):

> Don't expect clipboard related commands to work whilst you are testing code in the console. Generally, the page is required to be active (Async Clipboard API) or requires user interaction (e.g. a user click) to allow (`document.execCommand('copy')`) to access the clipboard see below for more detail.

As such, when you try to `.click()` the "Paste Text" button (you've probably been using the wrong div in the tree):

```js
const clickablePasteText = document.querySelector("#inputGridContainerRef > div.MuiGrid-root.MuiGrid-container.css-1tze8m4 > div > div > div");
clickablePasteText.click();
```

... you'll get an error message "Paste permission denied!" native to the website – it seems to assume that any exception thrown is caused by a missing permission:

[image: demonstration of error message "Paste permission denied!"]

but it is actually the browser complaining that the call to the API came without a valid user-triggered event. For example, Firefox throws an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Clipboard write was blocked due to lack of user activation.
```